# Best scripting language for ocr'd pdf renaming?

Tags: pdf, batch-rename

What I wanted is for a scripting language that will allow for a script to read the upper third of a particular ocr'd pdf file and rename the file based on keywords (name of companies, date sent, whether it be email, letter or fax, title), which will be cross-checked with a 'database' txt file containing these keywords.

My only scripting experience is using batch scripting to make a script that will move/copy and group files based on their date modified (I doubt batch will be powerful enough for what I'm thinking of doing). So the scripting language I'm thinking of should be easy and simple enough that I can learn it during down-times at work.

Comment: In what format is the OCR'd PDF file? I guess this would be a text file?

Comment: Still in pdf but OCR'd (via the default one in Acrobat)

Comment: That may be no good. Converting a PDF containing text elements is nearly as computationally complex as converting an image - PDFs are meant only to be printed. Can your OCR software output just a text file?

Comment: I have separate software for that, A-PDF extractor (GUI only) and the old version of xpdf (command line, I can't make the newer poppler version work). PDF OCR just OCRs the file and leave it at that.

Comment: (I've tried to find an old post about converting PDFs to text, and why it is so complicated, but I cannot now find it. It's on this site somewhere...).

Comment: Right, your response now makes things less clear, unfortunately. Presumably the keywords for each PDF will come from the OCR text, but if that can only be operated manually (via a GUI) then you cannot automate this process anyway. What important detail have I misunderstood?

Comment: Is the information you are looking for always more or less at the same place? I am thinking of using an Acrobat JavaScript for extracting the information and saving the file, and an Acrobat Action for the batch processing.

Comment: Some keywords would be in one .txt file like company names or if its email,letter or fax (tagged with 'email' or 'fax' if email or fax was found in the pdf, letter otherwise). Other keywords like title or dates, if possible will be taken from the pdf file (for example every bolded string found is the title of the pdf )